# My div disappears strangely

Tags: html, ios, css

when you visit the follow page http://tyzxhfamil.0613.npycom.com/yhd1/d.html  **on your iphone**(my ios version is ios 10.2.1), the red div disappears strangely.

I have found four solutions:

1. remove "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;"
2. remove "-webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg);"
3. remove gray background
4. reduce yellow div's height to a value, such as "2000px"

However, these styles are necessary for me.

Does anyone know any solutions that could fix this and **not** **remove** these exisiting styles?

Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">

   #main {
    
       width: 100%;
       height: 1000px;
       -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
       overflow: auto;
   
   }
   .wrap {
    
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: gray;
    
   }
   .rotate {
    
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg);

   }
   
   .blank {
    
    background: yellow;
    height: 10000px;
   }
   
   
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <!-- this div content could scroll -->
  <div id="main">
   
   <!-- this div has background -->
   <div class="wrap">
    
    <!-- the div disappears -->
    <div class="rotate"></div>
    
   </div>
   
   <!-- only for take place to make the conent could scroll -->
   <div class="blank"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason you only do `-webkit-transform` and not the generic one without the prefix? Also, I know the transform-origin is supposed to have the same default value on all browsers, but do try to set it to a specific location, just in case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tried your ways and added the transform-origin works, while the transform-origin's value cannot be set to "center center".And I want its value to be that. Anyway, thank you very much!